# java sql server fetching error

Tags: java, sql-server, unix

I am trying to connect to SQL Server by Java on Unix.

- When I used Mac OSX, there is no problem. I can connect to SQL Server and fetching rows on my other windows machine.
- I can do this step on Windows Machine, again there is no problem. I can getting rows.

But When I tried this on HP UX Itanium Unix Server,

I can connect sql server **but I can't get any rows.**

- There is no any firewall among server and clients
- There is no any constrain among server and clients
- I am not getting any exceptions. The cursor is just waiting.

What can I do on this? I am really stack at somewhere I don't know.

Here is my Java Code;

```
package javaSQL;
import java.lang.*;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.management.Query;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

        Class c = Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        Driver drv = (Driver) c.newInstance();
        Connection conn = drv.connect("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:2301;databaseName=Shelter; user=new_user; password=12345678",null);

        System.out.println("Connection is established.." + conn);
        System.out.println("Query is executing...");

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("select * from AlarmList"); 
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        System.out.println("AREA_NAME|MIN|PERSID|TEL|SMS|STARTDATE|ACTIVATED");

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.print(rs.getString("areaName") + "|");
            System.out.print(rs.getString("duration") + "|");
            System.out.print(rs.getString("senderName") + "|");
        }

    }

    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }


}       


}
```

Really Thanx,
Regards
Gokhan

Comment: Do you get the `Connection is established..` message?

Comment: As far as I see you tried to connect to `127.0.0.1` which is localhost but not an external Windows machine. Or did you configure a bridge from port 2301 to the windows machine?

Comment: Yes @PeterPaulKiefer right, If differnet IP can you telnet from given IP and port

Comment: How does the Table "AlarmList" look like (exact Name of Fields,...)?

Comment: Hi Guys, @PeterPaulKiefer,of course I am trying different IP insteadf of 127.0.0.1. It just was missed. sorry about this. The Ip is like 123.123.123.123 and the port 2301 I configured. I can telnet to this IP and port and result is fine. I can the establish. yes I am getting Connection is established message. . the field names are "areaName", "duration", "senderName". Thanks Regards

Comment: Are you sure that the jdbc connection is the problem and not the buffer of the output stream? Please replace the last `System.out.print` by a `System.out.println`. It's just a wild guess and perhaps you have removed such a println from the example code above ;-).  Or Unix JDBC is case sensitive and the used table name `AlarmList` from the select statement  does not match the real name in the database. (But then the code should throw an exception ???)  I would also add an println after the ` while (rs.next()){...}` loop to see if it hangs in the next() method or if there is no result.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer thanks for comments. But As I said I can connect and got the rows centOS Linux, MacOX there is no problem. When I tried to connect SQL Profiler can see my attempt and I can login on SQL Server by code but after login When I tried ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(); SQL Profiler see nothing.. Also I am getting println result :) 

System.out.println("Connection will establish....");
 System.out.println("Connection Established... : " + conn);

Comment: Sorry, those were my remaining ideas. There are no more left. ;-) It seams that the jdbc driver might not work on HP-UX. If I had the problem, i would try to debug the executeQuery method (that make no fun if you have no access to the sources) or perform an ordinary statement  instead of a prepared statement to see if that could change the situation. Or use a network sniffer on the hpux machine to inspect to jdbc drivers network traffic.

Comment: well, Again thank you for your time:) @PeterPaulKiefer. When the time, I wrote this comment, I was figuring the problem out :) The jdbc driver rar package provided by Microsoft has 2 driver jar file. sqljdbc4.jar ad sqljdbc.jar file. The problem was driver like you said. I was using sqljdbc4.jar file. I tried the other one unnecessarily which is sqljdcb.jar and It worked surprisingly.

Thanks Regards :)

Comment: Well, I thought of a wrong jdbc version but then I forgott to mention it. :-( Would you be so kind and add an answer to your question and mark it as the accepted answer. Perhaps someone is looking for the same problem and that helps him/her to find it. I upvote the question and would also upvote the answer to give the search algorithms a hint ;-)

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer thanks for everything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jdbc driver rar package provided by Microsoft has 2 driver jar files. **sqljdbc4.jar** and **sqljdbc.jar** file. The problem was driver. I was using **sqljdbc4.jar** file. I tried the other one unnecessarily which is **sqljdcb.jar** and It worked surprisingly. Thanks Regards :)

[image]